# Кнопки перехода в слайдшоу на drupal'e

Tags: drupal, cms

Сделал на сайте, который написан на drupale, слайдшоу c помощью модулей views и views slideshow. Подскажите , пожалуйста, как добавить кнопки переключатели слайдов,чтобы они стояли слева и справа.

Comment: а сейчас они вообще есть?

Comment: в данный момент просто слайдшоу , без кнопок, но я бы хотел что то  наподобе этого слайдшоу http://ks-el.ru/. Только в чем отличие, как я понимаю этот сайт написан на джумле, а я пишу на друпале

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кнопки включаются в настройках views для слайдера. 
Размещение кнопок можно настроить в css.